# HTML z index overlapping now

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm having trouble trying to figure what happend to my button at http://www.hirelogo.com Originally it was acting well and below the "easy" box, but now it is hovering above. I can't figure out what I changed if anything. I was not working on this area of the site. can someone let me know how to solve this. As I said I'm trying to get the button below the easy row. Thanks

Comment: I tried z-index 3000; both the row div and the easy div. The reason I am confused is I wasn't working on this portion of the site. I jsut happen to navigate back to the homepage and then it wasn't working anymore. The css I was creating else where had totally different names so I know that is not the case. I also tried different position: ; attributes

Comment: Have you tried actually removing your changes, even though you don't think they're relevant?

Comment: I haven't quite done that yet. The only changes that I made were to an img  and pre class so I'm really not sure why that might alter it, but I'll try it.

Comment: You may have also inadvertently put extra characters in a CSS selector somewhere, or failed to close a declaration, or your `img` tag pushed something somewhere else. If the only thing you've changed is the CSS file, then you caused problem. Left alone, CSS doesn't just "break" out of the blue.

Comment: Sheesh! Frustrating. That didn't seem to do the trick. I could not find any errors or left out ;'s.

Comment: Did you actually revert your file to the original version, or did you take out your changes by hand? Unless you reverted, there's still every chance that an unintentional edit you made is responsible.

Comment: I give up. I just increased my margin. I can't even remember how to actually do it correctly. This should do for now until I've solved the problem. I don't watn to reset because it takes me back to monday. I don't want to lose all of that. How do you normally revert back?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, I see

```
position: absolute: top:-20;
```

It should be

```
position: absolute; top:-20px;
```

Not sure if that's causing your error, but it's definitely *an* error.

Comment: woah. that wasn't the error, but definitely important. I think I may not be wrapping my mind correctly around it anymore. It made sense enough for me to do it initially, but I can't duplicate it. Tricky stuff my friend

Comment: I'm happy to help fix it, but I'm not sure exactly what it's supposed to look like. Do you have a screenshot or something of what it should be? Also, I notice the div containing those 3 text callouts is dark grey in background - if I expand the div to hold the floated divs with "overflow:hidden" then it gets a grey background. Is that supposed to happen?

Comment: I don't have a screenshot, but I am trying to layer the sections. Bottom layer would be the darkest color div which should be called splashyWrap followed by layer 2 "not convinced see more" (buttonOverlapStuff) and on the very top (Easy,speedy commited) row. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Also I took out the background color I believe. That may have just been a place filler left in. How are you expanding the div? Are just referring to the width and height?

Comment: Ok, so just change the order of the divs in the HTML, then - wrapSplashWords should go before splashyWrap. Re: the other div, the elements inside it are floated, which means it's technically got no height. I generally add "overflow:hidden" to these sorts of container divs, so they don't "disappear" - but when I did this to yours, I got grey background.

Comment: okay I'm going to loook a bit more into ordering. See if I can't figure it out. I believe I took out the background color. I'm not sure why you're still getting that. Which div are you viewing it on?